# C/C++ file on JNI folder filled with errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-studio, java-native-interface

### Background

In the past, I've made a nice Android library (link [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations)) that allows the developers to contain a bitmap within C/C++ world, play with it, and later convert it back to Java's world.

### The problem

Now that I try to import it, I fail to do so on both Eclipse and Android-Studio.

For Android-Studio, I can understand, since it doesn't really support it well yet, but for Eclipse, I've done it many times and it worked fine. I've even made a tutorial based on the problems I've collected over time.

No matter what I do, this is what I get:

[image]

A lot of errors in the form of "Type 'X' could not be resolved" .

This also leads to failure in creating the files the sample needs in order to run.

On Android Studio, I get this error:

[image]

### System Info

Windows 8.1 64bit, Eclipse 4.4.1, ADT 23.0.4.1468518, NDK r10d 64bit

### The question

How do I fix it?

What is wrong with my library?

Also, what should I do in order to allow Android Studio users import it?

Comment: I'm not an Eclipse guy but it looks like something is wrong with NDK configuration/location.

Comment: But NDK is installed just fine... It's just a file that I extract... Can you please try it out? to see if you can import and run the sample?

Comment: I don't have eclipse installed, but in Android Studio I can import and run the example just fine.

Comment: Really? can you please post it ? Maybe via Google Drive? So that I could import and run it?

Comment: Post what? I use the copy from the master of your github repo. Have you tried to google what may be causing it, for example https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android+ndk+aborting+stop

Comment: yes, but nothing has helped. Please just compress what you have that works, and let me try it out. maybe something went completely wrong here.

Comment: *A lot of errors in the form of "Type 'X' could not be resolved..."* - does it build? I have a similar open question at [How to change built-in C/C++ paths pointing to a deleted android-ndk-r9 installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27898114/608639). I think I have the some of the same symptoms, but the project builds and the `libs` directory is populated.

Comment: @jww All of the errors are in this format, so there isn't much to look at . Also, it's not blurry at all. Just open the image on a new tab. about it being built, if I run the app, it crashes because it can't find the needed compiled C/C++ code...

Comment: I clone your project and do the same step in `README.md`, and didn't find the errors as you described. Eclipse 4.4.1 with latest ADT installed.

Comment: @alijandro I know. I didn't have those issues in the past. I have no idea what's going on... Have you also tried opening the C/CPP file and seeing if it shows any errors? It's quite annoying to edit this file this way... Have you also tried Android-Studio?

Comment: The C/C++ files are fine in Eclipse, no error show and the whole project can be built and run without error. Sadly I had the error when do the `:JniBitmapOperationsLibrary:compileDebugNdk` compile tasks in Android studio.

Comment: @alijandro so you don't see what I've shown on the screenshot (on Eclipse) ? how odd. I've tried to re-install the NDK and Eclipse, but it still occurred . About Android Studio, that's even harder, as I'm quite a newb with it. Wish it was simpler and easier. It's just a single file...

Comment: Related: there's now an open bug report on AOSP for this issue under Eclipse: [Eclipse/ADT plugin cannot locate symbols for r10d NDK](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=97023).

Comment: @jww So others have it too?

Comment: @jww I have : Eclipse 4.4.1, ADT 23.0.4.1468518 , NDK r10d 64bit, Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved)

Comment: @jww Now that Eclipse's ADT&NDK plugins are no longer being supported by Google, my question goes to how to do it on Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with my library?

I don't think anything is wrong with your library. I believe this is a bug in ADT under Eclipse. See these AOSP bugs:

- [Issue 33788: [ADT 20] Indexer support regression](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788)
- [Issue 97023: Eclipse/ADT plugin cannot locate symbols for r10d NDK](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=97023)

---

> How do I fix it?

Well, there are lots of workarounds offered in [Issue 33788: [ADT 20] Indexer support regression](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788). Some of them are from AOSP and some of them are from regular users.

---

> what should I do in order to allow Android Studio users import it?

Sorry, I can't help here because I don't use Android Studio. I know Android Studio ignores `Application.mk` and `Android.mk`, so you might need to add the paths through `gradle.build` (I think that's what its called).

(It appears the ADT plugin under Eclipse builds paths by parsing `Application.mk` and `Android.mk`).

Answer (score 0):

As you know Google announced the new update of Android studio 1.3 RC3, and finally we get C++ support. I configure my app this way and everything working just fine.

Fallow this steps...

1. Run Android Studio 1.3 RC3  and click `Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)`
2. See [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) and [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) to configure your app.
3. In `project structure` (cmd + ; in Mac OS) set `Gradle version` to `1` `and Android Plugin Version` **`leave blank`**
4. Then configure you **app.gradle** file

   ```
    android.ndk 
    {

       moduleName = "MY_MODULE_NAME" 

       // this is your additional include files, 
       // do this if you have subfolder inside of JNI folder
       cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources")}".toString()
       cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources/Helper")}".toString()
       cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources/Image")}".toString()
       cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources/Utils")}".toString()

       // add c++ 11 support
       cppFlags += "-std=c++11"

       // your libs
       ldLibs += ["log", "jnigraphics"]

       stl     = "gnustl_static"
   }
   ```

if you want to use for example **cpufeatures** , you must add it to your JNI folder. Then in **app.gradle** file specify path to it in this way .

```
cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/cpufeatures")}".toString()
```

My **app.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 21
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.testapp"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 17
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        }

    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "MY_MODULE_NAME" 

        // this is your additional include files, 
        // do this if you have subfolder inside of JNI folder
        cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources")}".toString()
        cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources/Helper")}".toString()
        cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources/Image")}".toString()
        cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/myFolder/Sources/Utils")}".toString()

        // add c++ 11 support
        cppFlags += "-std=c++11"

        // your libs
        ldLibs += ["log", "jnigraphics"]

        stl     = "gnustl_static"
    }
    // jni is the default dir; config this if yours is in different directory
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs 'src/main/jni'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create ("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create ("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create ("x86-32") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        // build one including all productFlavors
        create("fat")
    }
}
```

My **project gradle** file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My **gradle-wrapper.properties** file

```
#Mon Jul 20 16:12:41 AMT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-rc-1-all.zip
```

P.S my reputation is not allowing me to post images, sorry